# New to AJAX and need some clarification

Tags: ajax

I had been in strucutured programming like COBOL and trying to learn AJAX now.

I saw this piece of code in w3schools and have the following questions?

**Questions:**
1. How does xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() this function would be evaluated. Is it not the xmlhttp.open() and xmlhttp.send() would need to be performed before the return is evaluated?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you to use jQuery , even if you are not familiar with it , at least its ajaxing with ease .

Answer (score 0):

**A**JAX is *asynchronous*.

Once you call `send()`, the browser will send the request in the background.

When the server replies, the browser will call your `onreadystatechange` handler; this happens some time after the rest of your code runs.

Comment: So, when the server response is delayed will it wait till the response is sent?

Comment: @user1050619: No; nothing ever waits.  It just won't call the callback until even later.